# Flutter best architecture patterns

Tags: flutter

I came from MVC and VIPER world and now I am new to Flutter cross-platform development. I really like declarative things it brings (like SwiftUI for example does as well). I see a lot of advantages in React architecture that Flutter uses to update UI with the most recent data. Though I still try to understand a conception of widgets. In my head, a word widget is more about UI things, but the documentation says that all in Flutter is a widget.

Let me highlight a simple example. Also, let's forget about declarative UI things.

In the iOS world using Objective-C or Swift, we usually separate a lot of layers such as data layer, UI layer, service layer, some helper layers and etc.

As you may notice we can't simply call these layers widgets, but looks like flutter can, but I may be wrong.

In the iOS world, I would like to use VIPER or some similar architecture pattern to separate different layers or add some services which request some data for me or do save it into the database.

What are the similar approaches or architecture patterns which I can use to follow best practice recommendations to achieve the best result, because as for me if we call some service which saves data to the database as a widget it's a bit strange. I would like to call it more service rather than a widget.

Do I need to write a widget for all such things? Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: Hi guys, It's been a long time since you asked this question. Do you have any idea now?

Comment: I think you shouldn't read "everything is a widget" too literally. Flutter itself is the UI Toolkit. So "everything" in the UI is a Widget. Which will make more sense. There are widgets (Like InheritedWidget) which aid in architecture, but generally flutter is not concerned with the business logic. This would be pure dart. Just like in iOS you have UIKit oder SwiftUI, but your business logic has nothing to do with UIKit and SwiftUI. (Everything is a widget means the UI is built on widgets vs. e.g. Android which has Activities, Fragments and Views as base UI elements)

Answer (score 17):

> Do I need to write widget for all such things? Or did I get it wrong?

Let me start by saying that flutter is flexible enough to allow you to adopt any pattern you have been using before and from MVVM, MVC, Redux, Mobx, Bloc, Provider, Riverpod etc pp there are many patterns out there which you can lean on.

Q: Do all services have to be widgets?

A: It depends.

Lets talk about "getting" the services first (dependency injection)

Using Widgets is just one way of doing dependency injection in Flutter which has the huge benefit of being scoped (only available to the children of the widget) and also of being disposed when this part of the widgettree is no longer needed (a bit over simplified).

There are other DI systems like getIt which don't rely on the widget tree - and you can do fancy stuff with getIt which is cumbersome to do in many of the others which rely on the build context to provide access to the object.

Imho in most cases you would not want to have your logic/ service in a widget but in a separate class which is then "provided" via a widget (e.g. using Provider, or by injecting it via getIt into the widget).

About "best practices":

There are many cool patterns which all have their pros and cons.

If you have a big team or the developers are changing often you might want to use a more rigid and biased system like BLOC (using the bloc library) - if you are solo or have enough time on your hands to do your own research, there might be patterns which better suit your needs. There is no one size fits all answer to this question.

For further research I would point towards the [Flutter Architecture samples](https://fluttersamples.com/) and the corresponding [Github repo, there might be more examples in the Pull Request section](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples)